# I want to click a button on 3rd window,which is an active element

Tags: java, selenium

First window is Parent window. then it populates two child window, some times while i inspect it shows 2 windows some times it shows 3 windows. I have to find a solution to switch on active window and to click the active element using Java.

Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println(driver.getWindowHandles().size());

```
        for(String WinID : driver.getWindowHandles() ) {
            System.out.println(WinID);
            driver.switchTo().window(WinID);
          driver.findElement(Group.btnmodexit).click();
        }
```

Comment: Can you share your piece of code where you are switching to 3rd window.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow,  please read section how to ask question, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Explain thoroughly with code samples what piece that you're stuck and need help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure why its not working for u, it works fine for me. U getting all opened tabs in array list then jumping to required tab by index, which is u passing to method by property.

```
    public void switchBetweenTabs(int tabIndex)
{
    ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList(driver.getWindowHandles());

    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(tabIndex));
}
```

Then click on your button.